# In threading program when do you use Invoke?

Tags: c#, multithreading, invoke

Example code:

```
private  void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread r= new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoWork));
    r.Start();
}

private void DoWork()
{
    MessageBox.Show("test");
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
}
```

When would a developer replace the `MessageBox` code with:

```
this.Invoke(new Action(() => { MessageBox.Show(this, "test"); }));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would use `this.Invoke` when you need the action to be executed on the UI thread.

For instance, if you were updating a UI element this would need to be executed on the Main UI thread.

Otherwise you would get an exception along the lines of:

> Cross-thread operation not valid: Control accessed from a thread other
>   than the thread it was created on.

In your example, there's obviously no need to use `Invoke`

Comment: When I use the code with out invoke, then also the messagebox shows up.. Is it only to update things like textbox control, label control, etc?

Comment: Sorry Im just learning this concept.. Is it only to update things like textbox control, label control, and other form controls?

Comment: The controls only work in a specific thread - if you set their properties or call their methods you can (and most likely will) get errors

Comment: It's interacting with Win32 or COM objects, which are single threaded by design. Pure .NET controls don't share that weakness.

Comment: MessageBox isn't owned by the UI thread so it will work either way. Try adding an item to a ComboxBox from another thread for example and you will see that it doesn't work.

Comment: @helloworld Yes, as you said it is only to update controls owned by the form from another thread.

Answer (score 3):

You use `Invoke` when you need to run code on the GUI thread. No more no less.

As to your last question, the only reason I can think of to do that is when you want to block your GUI thread until the user clicks the message box. There's no *need* for it.

Comment: I would argue with "No more no less".  There are times when you do want to execute on the GUI thread, but don't use `Invoke`, and you instead use `BeginInvoke`, which doesn't block the calling [removed: GUI] thread.

Comment: oh ... it *will* block the UI thread - just not the current one

Comment: @user2588666, of course it does, it doesn't block the *calling* thread.